# Unable to deploy to goerli

Tags: node.js, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js

I've given deploy.js in scripts folder

```
async function main() {
    const Collection = await ethers.getContractFactory("Collection")
    const collection = await Collection.deploy()
    await collection.deployed()
   console.log("Contract deployed to address:", collection.address)
   }

 main()
   .then(() => process.exit(0))
   .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error)
     process.exit(1)
    })`
```

Gave Collection.sol in contracts folder

Tried to deploy using this command

```
 npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli
```

Not getting an error, but not deploying.

Answer (score 0):

Do you check you have in your hardhat config file the Goerli network?

To use the `--network` flag you must have it in your `hardhat.config.js` as shown in the [Hardhat Docs](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network)

For example, you could use the following config file as example:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: { 
    version: "0.8.17",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 5000,
      },
    },
  },
  networks: {
    mumbai: {
      url: `https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/${YOUR_ALCHEMY_API_KEY_MUMBAI}`,
      accounts: [`${YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    },
  }
};
```

Hope to help you!